# Picasso not loading image from local file

Tags: android, image, bitmap, filesystems, picasso

I have a View that normally gets its image from online. But when the online image is not available (e.g. in airplane mode), the image can be loaded from the local file system if available. But Picasso is not loading the image. I am using logging to track progress so I know everything is done to make the call to picasso. How do I print the error if one exists? Or better yet, how do I fix the problem? **Again** everything works fine when the same code is working with a url from the server.

Here is the path to the local file:

```
 /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20140922_162920-1.jpg
```

Here is the code

```
private void addBkgFromLocalCache(String uriStr) {
    if (null != uriStr) {
        Log.i(TAG, "bkg uirstring is not null: " + uriStr);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriStr);
        Log.i(TAG, "bkg uri is : " + uri);

        Picasso.with(this).load(uri).into(new Target() {

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Loading bkg from local: call from inside picasso");
                setActivityBackground(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also I get the same no image problem if I use `File f = new File(uriStr)` instead of the Uri.

Answer (score 0):

I have also same problem when use Glide it's working fine

```
   Glide.with(context)
        .load(file)
        .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.mipmap.outline_slow_motion_video_black_24)
        .override(300,300)
        .centerCrop())
        .into(holder.imageview_dynimages);
```